# On button tap Touchdown or click, Which event to use? Any diff?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, touch

I have a WPF application which will be used in tablet and pc both. So I have little confusion about which event to use on button tap. Click or any touch event?
I just want that everything works fine on touch device and I don't have touch device to test.

Comment: I guess touch events may not be available on a non-touch devices. So Click seems to be good enough for both kind of devices.

Comment: All touch related events are mapped to desktop events like the click event, so handling those will cover both mouse clicks and finger taps.

Comment: For a `Button` control, please handle `Click`, not `Tapped`.